# Не обновляется свойство класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Только сейчас заметил, что `C#` не обновляет свойства классов, в реальном времени.
Есть свойство в классе `Str`:

```
private static readonly string str= !"".Equals(PlayerPrefs.GetString("str")) ? PlayerPrefs.GetString("str") : "str";
```

Когда я изменяю, где-то в другом месте:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("str", "str2");
```

И вызываю:

```
print(Str.str);
```

У меня выводит `str`, за место заявленного `str2`.
Срабатывает, только после перезапуска...
Что делать и как быть?

О том, чтобы выяснять это где-то в методе, я не считаю правильным.
Почему вообще так происходит и с чем связано, сие чудо?
В других языках, не наблюдал такого, например в `Java` все работает должным образом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А с чего str должна стать "str2"? Ты определил его до того, как записать новое значение в PlayerPrefs. Всё равно что удивиться следующему:

```
void Start () {
    int a = 1;
    aChange(a);
    Debug.Log(a); // Почему в логе 1, а не 2 
}

void aChange (int a) {
    a = 2;
}
```

Это же не ссылка на объект, а значение. Либо ты ошибся с `static`. Конструктор для `static` вызывается всего 1 раз (первый) сколько бы экземпляров классов ты не создал. И в других языках это так-же... и в Java тоже... иначе как-бы у вас Singleton работал.

```
public static void LogTest () {
    Debug.Log("Result 1: "+ValueStr);
    ValueStr = "str2";
    Debug.Log("Result 2: "+ValueStr);
}

static string SaveValueStr;
public static string ValueStr {
    get {
        if (SaveValueStr == "") {
            SaveValueStr = PlayerPrefs.GetString("str");
            if (SaveValueStr == "") { SaveValueStr = "str"; }
        }
        return SaveValueStr;
    }
    set {
        SaveValueStr = value;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("str", SaveValueStr);
    }
}
```

Используй модификаторы доступа get/set.

Comment: Я совсем забыл про это.... Ну да ладно! А в java все работает должным образом, проверял.

Comment: Тогда вот так...

Comment: Все работает норм. Я порсто не туда вставлял =)